# How to email a unique link to user django allowing them to confirm availability for an event (and update the database as well)

Tags: django, django-urls, django-email

Here is the problem: I have a model called `invite` and a model called `person`. An invite is associated to a person and a person only and it has a field called `status`.

How can I send generate a url that I can then send to the `person` through an email so that if they click they can confirm availability to the `invite` and update the `status`.

I am thinking about using the `UUID` of the `invite` and adding a line on the `urls.py` calling a view that updates the status of the `invite with uuid`.

But I wonder if there is a better way that doesn't expose the UUID.

Comment: Is the UUID secret?  These kind of confirmation links are always long, because they have to carry state.  Does the UUID uniquely identify the responder, too, so you don't need to send a user ID?

Comment: you are right, I can just use the UUID. It was a silly question :)